# Rails 5: ActiveRecord query last object in a joined table with OR condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I need some help with querying here (Rails 5.1). I have a polymorphically-associated object named `Verification` (`belongs_to :verifiable, polymorphic: true`). Other objects, like `Comment`, can have `verifications` (`has_many :verifications, as: :verifiable`), the last one (sorted by `id`) being considered current. `Verification` has an enum property `status`. I need to retrieve comments that have a particular `user_id` (the one of the current user) OR *current* (i.e., last) verification object with correct status (say, `approved`).

So, I’m trying:

```
self.where(user_id: user.id).or(self.joins(:verifications).limit(1).where(verifications: { status: 'approved' }))
```

But Rails gives me the following error:

```
Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins, :references, :limit]
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make it work in just one query (My Arel attempt failed). So hopefully the following would suffice (tested working):

```
latest_verification_ids = Verification.group(:verifiable_id).maximum(:id).values

# SELECT MAX("verifications"."id") AS maximum_id, "verifications"."verifiable_id" AS verifications_verifiable_id FROM "verifications" GROUP BY "verifications"."verifiable_id"

comments_whose_user_id_is_user_id_or_whose_last_verification_is_approved =
  Comment
    .where(user_id: user_id)
    .or(
      Comment.where(id:
        Comment.joins(:verifications)
          .where(
            verifications: {
              id: latest_verification_ids,
              status: 'approved'
            }
          )
      )
    )

# SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."user_id" = ? OR "comments"."id" IN (SELECT "comments"."id" FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "verifications" ON "verifications"."verifiable_id" = "comments"."id" AND "verifications"."verifiable_type" = ? WHERE "verifications"."id" IN (4, 2) AND "verifications"."status" = ?))  [["user_id", 1], ["verifiable_type", "Comment"], ["status", "approved"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jay-Ar! This worked, but with one caveat: it only gives x objects (due to `limit(x)` parameter). If this parameter is left out, this query gives all Comments with at least one verification having the desired status. But I need to check only the first verification of _every_ Comment with `where(verifications: {status: 'approved'})` condition. Have any ideas?

Comment: I removed the limit(1). Even though this is removed, it should work already properly. As for performance, I'm not too sure yet if removing the limit would have much slower impact.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing it checks all verifications, and if it finds at least one satisfying the condition—includes the Comment in results. You can try it yourself, if you have a test model for it. Adding a couple verifications and changing statuses for them in different combinations proves it. There just has to be a way to retrieve only the first object from joined collection, but I can't figure it...

Comment: Ohh i thought you intend to get all comments that have at least one verification(having status == 'approved'), but seems like you only want comments that have last verification (having status == 'approved'). I'm updating my answer.